# .style.animation - "многоразовое использование" onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css3

пытаюсь к *onclick* привязать анимацию, которая меняет цвет текста, но *onclick* работает лишь единожды.

```js
document.querySelector('#blackred').onclick = () => {
document.querySelector('#blackred').style.animation = 'blackred 1s ease';
}
```

```css
@keyframes blackred {
0% {color:black;}
50% {color:red;}
100% {color:black;}
}
```

```html
<h1 id="blackred">HI!</h1>
```

задумывалось, что на *onclick* можно кликать до бесконечности (**не** зацикленная анимация, **не** *animation-iteration-count: infinity*), а получается что анимация работает только 1 клик, прошу дать информативный ответ, как решить эту проблему, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант: можно с помощью reflow перезапустить анимацию

```js
document.querySelector('#blackred').onclick = (event) => {
  event.target.style.animation = 'none';
  event.target.offsetHeight; // reflow
  event.target.style.animation = 'blackred 1s ease';
}
```

```css
@keyframes blackred {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="blackred">HI!</h1>
```